# Why does the door slide mode need to be changed after the jetway or stairs are detached?

Tags: airliner, aircraft-systems, doors

Why does the door slide mode need to be changed after the jetway or stairs are detached? Does the mode only need to be set when the door is closed?

Comment: Don't know if it is a exact duplicate. I think the question is asking exactly when the door should be armed: when the outside stairs/jetbridge is removed, or if it can be done while they are still outside (which is bad, since the slide will impact the stair or jetbridge).

Comment: Duplicates to SE are for duplicate questions, not two questions with duplicate answers. If the _question_ is not a duplicate, it's not supposed to be marked as one.

Comment: @CGCampbell I happen to disagree, but that's what the voting system is for. Why don't you vote to re-open?  If 5 other people agree with you, it will be so.

Comment: @CGCampbell Note that the duplicate template says "*This question already has an answer here*". So, there is at least some ambiguity in when to VTC as duplicate.